# UIDynamicAnimator, removeAllBehaviors() doesn't work at first time

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uidynamicanimator

I have UIDynamicAnimator property defined:

```
lazy fileprivate var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = {
        return UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)
}()
```

self is subclass from UIView;

In extension of self class, the same file, I have logic with animations, that uses my animator, adds UIDynamicBehavior items:

```
    let pushBehavior = UIPushBehavior(items: [stampView], mode: .continuous)
//some settings
    let dynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [stampView])
//some settings
    let gravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [stampView])
//some settings
    let collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [stampView])
//some settings
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to stop all animations with removeAllBehaviors() animations stop, but behaviors all still in animator.behaviors. The second time I call it, array becomes empty.

//======

For my pushBehavior I add action, which changes var, indicated, that I achieve destination point:

```
pushBehavior.action = { [unowned stampView] in
            if stampView.center.x <= endPosition.x {
                lastJump = true
            }
        }
```

In collisionBehavior delegate method I check this variable and try to stop animations with removeAllBehaviors()

```
public func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
    if lastJump {
        //animator.behaviors.count = 4
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        //still, animator.behaviors.count = 4
    }
}
```

Comment: You are showing totally the wrong code! I don't see `removeAllBehaviors` anywhere in your code. Please show _that_ code, and show how you know that the behaviors are not being removed.

Comment: @matt is it better now?

Comment: Yes, now I can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are testing like this:

```
public func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
    if lastJump {
        //animator.behaviors.count = 4
        animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        //still, animator.behaviors.count = 4
    }
}
```

Well, `animator.removeAllBehaviors()` is a command that the behaviors *should* be removed, but that command cannot be obeyed *now*, because those behaviors are still operating, *including the one your code is right in the middle of*. If the behaviors *really* stopped right at that instant, we would never even reach the next line of your code!

So the animator rightly does not in fact remove the behaviors until *after your code has stopped running* (also known as the end of the run loop).

The way to work around this to wait until *after* your code has stopped before calling `removeAllBehaviors()`. You can easily do that using my `delay` utility (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994):

```
public func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
    if lastJump {
        delay(0.1) {
            animator.removeAllBehaviors()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but they are not removed after few seconds too. I have some action (let it be button tap, doesn't matter actually) and after animation stopped, I press this button, behaviors are still there

Comment: Okay, see my revised answer. But I think there is something more that you are not telling me.

Comment: yes, it is the issue. I'm trying to remove behavior in method, called from behaviors delegate property. all animations stop, but behaviors seems to be retained. thanks!